# The select command in the query

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join

I have two tables called Product and Unit, FieldID UnitID is a common field between the two tables.
In the form in which the product table is patched, there is a combo box that, when we give it, returns the UnitID value from the Unit table to the point where we have no problem.
My problem is when this Cambodox box is counted without the value, then it stores the 0 in the UnitID.
Now, when I want to SELECT, I will display all the values ​​except that the UnitID is equal to 0.

Access Bank:
SQLcode:

```
SELECT Unit.UnitID, Product.*
FROM Unit INNER JOIN Product ON Unit.UnitID = Product.UnitID
```

One of the ways to write SELECT is to display the same UnitIDs that are equal to 0.

Comment: `WHERE Unit.UnitID <> 0`? what DBMS are you using?

Comment: SELECT Unit.UnitID, Product.*
FROM Unit INNER JOIN Product ON Unit.UnitID = Product.UnitID where Unit.UnitID > 0;

Comment: Consider adding some helpful tags. E.g. SQlite or MySQL for the database your are using and another one for the programming language. This would probably get more attention by people in the know.

Answer (score 0):

Simply chain a `where` clause to filter out the records that do have a `UnitID` of `0`.

```
SELECT Unit.UnitID, Product.*
FROM Unit 
INNER JOIN Product ON Unit.UnitID = Product.UnitID
WHERE Unit.UnitID <> 0
```

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure your table structure, if you select which data where `Unit.UnitID != 0`

then

```
SELECT Unit.UnitID, Product.*
  FROM Unit INNER JOIN Product
  ON Unit.UnitID = Product.UnitID 
  where Unit.UnitID != 0;
```

or if you want to not equal or less then

```
SELECT Unit.UnitID, Product.*
 FROM Unit 
 INNER JOIN Product 
 ON Unit.UnitID = Product.UnitID
 where Unit.UnitID > 0;
```

if your filed Unit.UnitID return 0 or more then need decide then

```
 SELECT * from 
 (SELECT Unit.UnitID, Product.* 
  FROM Unit INNER JOIN Product
  ON Unit.UnitID = Product.UnitID) 
main where  main.UnitID != 0;
```

if you have not Unit.UnitID store then then use outer join which return all data if where condition not match so in this case if Unit.UnitID is not null then select all data

```
SELECT Product.*
FROM Product
LEFT OUTER JOIN Unit ON Product.UnitID = Unit.UnitID
```

last query not tested, if any problem then inform me

Comment: My dear friend thank you guy
But I think because Unit.UnitID does not store 0, this select can not display all values 
And only displays the values ​​that exist in both tables
If we only store 0 in Product.UnitID
I hope you understand what you mean

Comment: @narmafkar can you check my last answer section, in this case i hope it will work

Comment: @narmafkar not sure so i also guess just remove where condition from my last answer section.